# How to hide a templated non-member function from client's code?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, linkage

I have template functions, say,

```
template<class T> 
void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    size_t b, m, e,
    ...
    mysort(vec, b, m, e);
}

template<class T>
void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t b, size_t m, size_t e)
{
     size_t x, y, z;
     ...
     mysort (vec, x, y, z);
}
```

The public interface is the one take only a vector reference. I would like to hide the other one, the implementation, so that no client code can do

```
mysort(vec, a, b, c);
```

It doesn't feel right to create a class and make the implementation function private static, I try to use the anonymous namespace,

```
namespace abc 
{
    namespace 
    {
        template<class T>
        void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t b, size_t m, size_t e)..
    }

    template<class T> 
    void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec)...

}
```

It helps, but not exactly a knockout...

```
#include "mysort.h"

int main()
{
    ...
    abc::mysort(vec, a, b, c); // this won't compile, good
}
```

however if I change it to:

```
#include "mysort.h"

using namespace abc;

int main()
{
    ...
    mysort(vec, a, b, c); // it compiles and runs!!
}
```

I am using gcc Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5 on x86_64.
can anyone explain why it compiles with using directive, but not with qualified names, and whether there is a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: My first thought was that the anonymous namespace was dumping stuff into the global anonymous namespace and the using declaration wasn't even needed, but I was wrong.  Here's a SSSCE: http://codepad.org/kUTBPWxh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common idiom for this is to create a "detail" namespace, which is intended only for internally-used code:

```
namespace abc 
{
    namespace detail
    {
        template<class T>
        void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t b, size_t m, size_t e)..
    }

    template<class T> 
    void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec)...

}
```

To answer your question about the unnamed namespace behavior:

Unnamed namespaces (they're not called anonymous namespaces) are named a bit weird -- they're unnamed to you, but the compiler actually generates a unique internal name for it. Your example is equivalent to:

```
namespace abc 
{
    namespace def // lets say 'def' is unique.
    {
        template<class T>
        void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t b, size_t m, size_t e)..
    }
    using namespace def;

    template<class T> 
    void mysort(std::vector<T>& vec)...

}
```

You'll notice it behaves the same as your unnamed example: you can't do `abc::mysort(vec, 1, 2, 3)` here, but you can `using namespace abc; mysort(vec, 1, 2, 3)`.

This happens because there aren't two `abc::mysort`s, only a `abc::def::mysort` and `abc::mysort`. When you declared an actual `abc::mysort`, it hides the one brought in by `using namespace def`. Note if you comment out the 1-param `mysort`, you can actually say `abc::mysort(vec, 1, 2, 3)`.

Because it was hidden, a qualified call to `abc::mysort` must look at explicitly `abc::mysort`, and only finds the 1-param version.

However, with an unqualified call via `using namespace abc; mysort(vec, 1, 2, 3)`, it can use ADL to find any available function which matches.

Comment: @ethan: This way at least documents that it is a bad idea.

Comment: Indeed. All you can do is to not externally document the `detail` namespace, other than to say it is unsupported and may change drastically in future versions. This is a strategy used in pretty much every large template-based library today -- don't overcomplicate things!

Comment: This is just as good as `private`... it is compiler-assisted documentation.  C++ access modifiers do NOT provide security.  If it would help to call the namespace `abc_internal_use_only` then do that!  Of course nothing prevents any client from copying the code from your header file directly into theirs.

Comment: Updated to explain the unnamed namespace behavior!

Comment: @CoryNelson that makes sense, thanks for the answer. So there's no better way to prevent user from naming the "hidden" stuff?

Comment: Not really. As Ben said, this is little more than compiler-assisted documentation -- it should only stop someone from accidentally using it. If someone actually wants to still use it, there's nothing you can do to stop them from simply uncommenting `private` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more testing, actually, in a later version gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) and -std=c++0x, it does exactly what I expected.

In the main file, neither the using directive or using the qualified name will allow you to call a function inside an anonymous namespace that itself is inside another namespace.

I think the reason is the compiler confirms the latest standard, which says an unnamed namespace has internal linkage by default.

It seems to me, the unnamed namespace approach should be preferred to the old "detail" namespace practice.